# Is there a way to send push notifications without subscribing to the topic on firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to send push notifications to multiple devices without using the `subscribeToTopic()` function?

Comment: Then you need to store notification tokens for all devices, Then you can send them according to the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you don't want to subscribe to a topic then you can [send messages to device groups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group).

Comment: Hey. Can I help you with other information?